# Scipy Newton Krylov Expects Square Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am trying to use scipy.optimize.newton_krylov() to solve a least-squares optimization problem, i.e. finding x such that (Ax - b)**2 = 0. My understanding is that A has to be mxn with m>n, b has to be mx1, and x will be nx1. When I try to run the optimization, I get an error:

```
ValueError: expected square matrix, but got shape=(40, 6)
```

Presumably this error concerns the computation of the Jacobian and not my input matrix A? But if so, how can I change the values I am providing to the functions to resolve this problem? Any advice would be appreciated.

The following code reproduces the error:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton_krylov

A = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (40,6))
b = np.arange(40)
x0 = np.ones(6)

def F(x):
    return (A.dot(x) - b)**2

x = newton_krylov(F, np.ones(6))
```

Comment: The error indicates that it's expecting a square matrix and indicating that you supplied a 40x6 one, which is the same as your matrix A. Test a square matrix A first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docstring of `newton_krylov`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton_krylov.html) explains, it finds a root of a function `F(x)`.  The function `F` must accept a one-dimensional array, and return a one-dimensional array of the same size as the input.  If, for example, `x` has length 3, `F(x)` must return an array with length 3. In that case, `newton_krylov` attempts to solve `F(x) = [0, 0, 0]`.

The error that you got is the result of `newton_krylov` attempting to use the numerically computed [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of `F` with a function that expects the matrix to be square.  Your function `F` has a Jacobian matrix with shape (40, 6), because the input has length 6 and the output has length 40.

By itself, `newton_krylov` is not the right function to use for solving a least-squares problem.  A least-squares problem is a minimization problem, not a root-finding problem.  (A solver such as `newton_krylov` might be used to implement a minimization algorithm, but I assume you are interested in using an existing solution rather than writing your own.)

You say you want to solve a least-squares problem, but then you say "i.e. finding x such that (Ax - b)**2 = 0."  I assume that was just a bit a sloppiness in your description, because that is not the least-squares problem. The least-squares problem is to find `x` such that `sum((Ax - b)**2)` is minimized.  (In general, there won't be an `x` that makes the sum of squares *equal* to zero.)

So, assuming you really want to find `x` such that `sum((Ax - b)**2)` is minimized, you can use [`scipy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html).

For example:

```
In [54]: from scipy.linalg import lstsq

In [55]: A = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (40,6))

In [56]: b = np.arange(40)

In [57]: x, res, rank, s = lstsq(A, b)

In [58]: x
Out[58]: 
array([  5.07513787,   1.83858547,  18.07818853,   9.28805475,
         6.13019155,  -0.7045539 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Krylov method requires the first argument (function F(x) in your case) to be a square matrix.

This seems like a homework question but the answer will be adjusting matrix A to make it square. Examples: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#kk